# look up data left and right (with or without VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, lookup, vba

I have an excel file with 2 worksheets.

On the first worksheet called "data", I want to look up data from the second worksheet called "List". The data that I need to look up comes from the left and right of the look up value. Therefore, I would like to know your suggestion on the best formula or code to be collect data from the both side simulaniously.

```
Worksheet 1 name "Data" > Value to look up is in "B7" is "John"

Worksheet 2 name "List" > Matching value to be looked up is in "D7" is "John"
                    > Return a value from "A7" -3 cells to the left
                    > Return a value from "G7" 3 cells to the right
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming "Matching value to be looked up is in "D7" " means that the matching value is **somewhere** in column D, but you need to find where, this sounds like a job for the `MATCH` and `INDEX` Excel functions.

Comment: I have used MATCH and INDEX and it works just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you have tried,

But I would recommend using .Find and then Offsetting to the left and right.

So an example would be:

Msgbox(Worksheets("List").Range("D1:D20").Find(Worksheets("Data").Range("D7").Value).Offset(0,3).Value)
Msgbox(Worksheets("List").Range("D1:D20").Find(Worksheets("Data").Range("D7").Value).Offset(0,-3).Value)

Another option would be to use Index Match so

=Index(List!A:A,Match(Data!B7,List!D:D,0),1) for the left of it

and

=Index(List!G:G,Match(Data!B7,List!D:D,0),1) for the right of it

Hope this helps